# What does the inverse Function in R calculate?

Tags: r, quantiles

```
  library(GoFKernel)
  x<-seq(0,1000,33)
  f <- function(x) pbeta(x, shape1=2, shape2=3)
  f.inv <- inverse(f,lower=0,upper=1)
  f.inv(.5)
  [1] 0.3857168
```

I don't understand the result of the Code.

When I imagine the inverse function of `pbeta`, then on the $x$-axis are the probabilities and on the $y$-axis are the values from the $x$-variable.

Input `f.inv (.5)` is equal to the median or isn't it?

So I expected a value from the $x$-variable more exact 495. 
What is the meaning of the result 0.3857168?

The documentation was not a great help.

Comment: There is no `inverse` function in R. If you are using a package, you need to specify it.

Comment: Sorry. The package is GoFKernel.

Comment: It is pretty obvious from it's name and the description "Function to calculate the inverse function of a cumulative distribution function." ...

Comment: If there's a statistical question here you need to spell it out. You seem to be confusing the dummy variable `x` used inside the function `f` with the vector of integers `x`: the median of the Beta(2,3) distribution is indeed 0.3857, & the median of those integers is indeed 495, but one has nothing to do with the other & it's not clear why you think it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> pbeta(0.3857168,shape1=2, shape2=3)
[1] 0.4999812
```

Apart from that, your code

```
x<-seq(0,1000,33)
```

is useless, as this `x` is not used later in the given code. This may indicate a fundamental misunderstanding concerning the expression `<- function(x)...`